# How to show custom table row(<tr>) when there is no data(initial and after searching) in data-tables | datatables | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using data tables in my project and using the ajax option to fetch the data for the data table but I want to show the custom table row in case of the empty table, and different table row in case of no records after perform searching.

```
$('#clients-list-table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "ajax": {
        "url": SITE_URL + "/clients",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "type": "GET"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "email" },
        { "data": "tax_id", "searchable": false, "orderable": false },
        { "data": "phone", "searchable": false, "orderable": false },
        {
            "orderable":      false,
            "searchable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": "",
            "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                actionTd = '<i class="fa fa-sort-desc action-btn" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>';
                actionTd += '<div class="dropdown-menu"><ul>';
                actionTd += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">View</a></li>';
                actionTd += '<li><a href="'+SITE_URL+'/clients/'+data.id+'/edit">Edit</a></li>';
                actionTd += '<li><a class="delete_resource" data-resource="destroy-client-form-'+data.id+'" href="'+SITE_URL+'/clients/'+data.id+'">Delete</a><form method="POST" action="'+SITE_URL+'/clients/'+data.id+'" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="destroy-client-form-'+data.id+'" style="display: none"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="'+$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')+'"></form></li>';
                actionTd += '</ul></div>';
                return actionTd;
            }
        },
    ],
    render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        console.log(data.length);
    },
    rowCallback: function (row, data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    "oLanguage": { 
        "sZeroRecords": '<div class="message"><p>You have not yet create a new client!</p></div><div class="invoice-btns"><a href="'+SITE_URL+'/clients/create" class="btn-custom"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Client </a></div>' 
    }
});
```

Current HTML showing the following table row by using the above sZeroRecords option

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td valign="top" colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">
        <div class="message"><p>You have not yet create a new client!</p></div>
        <div class="invoice-btns"><a href="http://localhost/kedas/clients/create" class="btn-custom"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Client </a></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But I want to show the following HTML in case of no record

```
<tr class="no-data-row">
    <td colspan="7" rowspan="2" align="center">
        <div class="message"><p>You have not yet create a new client!</p></div>
        <div class="invoice-btns">
            <a href="'+SITE_URL+'/clients/create" class="btn-custom"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Client </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

After perform Searching it showing the same but I want to show some different table row like below

```
<tr class="no-search-data">
    <td colspan="7" rowspan="2" align="center">
        <div class="message"><p>There is no records match with your searchin</p></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you were pretty close. Look at my example:

```js
var jsonData = [
  { 
     "Name": "Tiger Nixon",
     "Position": "System Architect",
     "Office": "Edinburgh",
     "Age": 61,
     "StartDate": "2011/04/25",
     "Salary": "$320,800"
  },
  { 
     "Name": "Garrett Winters",
     "Position": "Accountant",
     "Office": "Tokyo",
     "Age": 63,
     "StartDate": "2011/07/25",
     "Salary": "$170,750"
  },
  { 
     "Name": "Ashton Cox",
     "Position": "Junior Technical Author",
     "Office": "San Francisco",
     "Age": 66,
     "StartDate": "2009/01/12",
     "Salary": "$86,000"
  }
];

var jsonData2 = []

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  lengthChange: false,
  pageLength: 10,
  language: {
     //zeroRecords: '<div class="fa-3x"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-spin"></i></div>',
     //emptyTable: '<div class="fa-3x"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>'
     // zeroRecords: '<div class="message"><p>There is no records match with your searchin</p></div>'
  },
  data: jsonData2, // replace with jsonData for records
  drawCallback: function( settings ) {
    var api = this.api();
    var searchText = api.search();
    var currentPageDataSet = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).data();

    if (searchText != '' && currentPageDataSet.length == 0) {
        var $tbody = $('#example tbody');
        $tbody.empty();
        var $tr = $('<tr class="no-search-data" role="row"></tr>');  
        $tr.append('<td colspan="5" rowspan="2" align="center"><div class="message"><p>There is no records match with your searching</p></div></td>');
        $tbody.append($tr); 
    } else if (currentPageDataSet.length == 0) {
        var $tbody = $('#example tbody');
        $tbody.empty();
        var $tr = $('<tr role="row" class="no-data-row"></tr>');  
        $tr.append('<td colspan="5" rowspan="2" align="center"><div class="message"><p>You have not yet create a new supplier!</p></div><div class="invoice-btns"><a href="#" class="btn-custom"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Client </a></div></td>');
        $tbody.append($tr);
    }
  },
  columns: [
      { data: 'Name' },
      { data: 'Position' },
      { data: 'Office' },
      { data: 'Age' },
      { data: 'StartDate' },
      { data: 'Salary' }
    ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<br><br>
<table id="example2" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I change the class of empty tr? As I need <tr class="no-data-row"> but it coming as <tr class="odd">

Comment: @SachinKumar: I'm sorry. I misunderstood your issue. I edited my example. Could you check it out, please?

Comment: I think you should use the condition something like this 

if (searchText != '' && currentPageDataSet.length == 0) {
 ...
} else if (currentPageDataSet.length == 0) {
 ...
}

Comment: Any way you do a great job. At least tell me the useful option for the data table.

Comment: @SachinKumar: The problem if I use your proposed condition, how would you know which class (**no-search-data** or **no-data-row**) to inject to the <tr> tag?

Comment: No look at your condition you just check if the search input is not empty then simply show the tr. but what about after searching you have some records. It means according to your condition it will always show the same result(empty tr) even there are some records to show after searching.(#example2 example)